# Sorting data placed in isolated storage

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7.1.1

I know how to store and retrieve data using isolated storage. My problem is how to sort the data I want to recover from that has already been stored previously. All my data is stored in a single file.

The user stores the data everyday and maybe on a particular date he makes two entries and none on some other day. In that case how should I search for the particular days info I need.

And could you also explain how data is stored in the isolated storage that is in packets of data or some other way? If I store two data sets in same file, does it automatically shift to a next line for storing other data or do I have to specify for it to do so?

Moreover, if I want to save data in the same line, does it automatically separate the data in a line by some tab or inserting some character in between two data sets in a line or does the developer have to take care of this?

Comment: How are you storing the current data? we will need to see some code in order to be able to suggest a retrieval mechanism? What data is stored and in what format is it stored as?

Comment: Did my post help at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the date is saved in the title of the file then you can use the following code to search for it:

```
var appStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
string date = appStorage.GetFileNames("the date you are looking for")
```

In answer to your other question if you use `.Write()` when writing text to a file, then it will create one long stream of data, if you use `.WriteLine()` then you will write the information, then a new line reference will be added at the end.

I'm not sure as you weren't very clear, but just in-case, here is a general procedure for reading files from IsolatedStorage:

```
var appStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(appStorage.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)))
    {
        fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();    
    }
```